# What does the orange part of my health bar mean?

Tags: like-a-dragon-ishin

My health bar in *Like A Dragon: Ishin* is divided into two sections: one red and one orange. What is the orange section of my health bar for? Is it some kind of bonus HP?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extra health points from Trooper cards are marked in orange, and they connect with the main red health bar. Unfortunately, this is not a permanent increase, as the size of the orange bar can change based on what cards you have equipped.

According to [GamePressure](https://guides.gamepressure.com/like-a-dragon-ishin/guide.asp?ID=67895).